# Dask "Column Assignment Doesn't Support Timestamp"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask

Trying to add a pandas datetime to a Dask DataFrame, reproduceable example below:

```
# library imports
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from dask import dataframe as dd 

# Load toy data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
DF = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)

# Convert Pands DataFrame to Dask DataFrame
ddf = dd.from_pandas(DF, npartitions = 2)

# Add a date column                                                                     
months_ago = 50
some_date = pd.datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(months=train_months_back)

# Add state column to DataFrame
DF['date_vintage']= some_date # works fine
ddf['date_vintage']= some_date # TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type Timestamp
```

> TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type Timestamp

How should I be adding a pandas datetime as a datetime (not string) column to a dask dataframe? I've found some resources on converting strings to dask datetimes, or datetime indices, but can't get this to work. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This looks like a bug.  I recommend [raising an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new)

Comment: thanks, issue filed at: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3159

Comment: fix merged into latest dask: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3164

Comment: Care to give an answer and mark it as correct?

Comment: hey sure will do, sorry under tight job deadline at the moment. happy to accept an answer too if you leave one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now implemented in dask versions >= 0.17.1

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.Timestamp(...)
```